# Amazon Athena - current_date - columnvalue difference as a day format

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

Amazon Athena table contains a column 'closed_date'.

```
closed_date
2002-05-12
2003-03-26
```

Now I need to find out the number of days after closing the account.

I am trying to do below:

```sql
select 
extract (current_date - closed_date) as day
from athena_table
```

Ideally, it should return (2021-07-27) - (2002-05-12) = 7,016 Days

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`DATE_DIFF(unit, timestamp1, timestamp2)`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html) command:

```sql
SELECT
  DATE_DIFF('day', CURRENT_DATE, closed_date) as days
FROM athena_table
```